# Cambiar a una imágen en específico al apretar un botón

Tags: c#, wpf

En la universidad estamos haciendo una aplicación que permita jugar ajedrez y nuestro grupo decidió que como parte del diseño y facilidad para jugar le agregaremos una zona en la que aparecieran las reglas del juego, incluidos los movimientos de cada pieza.

Queremos que al apretar cada botón de la pieza respectiva, la imagen de ayuda que está presente en la interfaz, cambie de acuerdo al botón que el usuario allá presionado, es decir, si el usuario presiona el botón `Rey` en la imagen que está presente en la pantalla aparezca una foto con los posibles movimientos del `Rey`. Y si decide presionar el botón `Caballo`, en la misma imagen aparezcan ahora los movimientos del `caballo`.

Las imágenes de los movimientos las tengo guardadas dentro de la misma solución en una carpeta en específico `Imágenes/Movimientos`.
Dentro del código adjunto está lo que tenemos hasta el momento para cambiar el texto contenido en un `.txt` de acuerdo al botón presionado y lo ideal sería hacer algo similar para poder cambiar la imagen.

```
private void btnRey_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.txtMovimientos.Text = " El rey simboliza la cabeza del ejército, es decir, el mismo jugador. (El resto del texto no lo colocaré ya que se entiende la idea).";
    this.txtMovimientos.ScrollToHome();
    this.lblImagen1.Content = "";
 }
```

Comment: Las imágenes son fijas? porque puedes agregarlas al proyecto y hacer referencia a ellas, y ya no necesitas tenerlas en la ruta.

Comment: Además de agregar las imágenes que necesitas al proyecto, también podrías agregar un complemento `imageList` en el cual agregues todas las imágenes a la colección en la propiedad `images` y acceder a ellas según necesites con tu botón.

Comment: Si, serían fijas las imágenes, solo cambiarían cuando aprete el botón, el problema que se me genera es el cómo las llamaría desde el botón y me las coloque dentro del objeto imagen que está ya fijo en la interfaz

Comment: Y cómo se colocaría las imágenes que tengo guardadas dentro de este imageList? Busqué bien como era la función pero no logro comprender totalmente como trabaja

Answer (score 0):

Para asignar la imagen podrias usar

```
string imagePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Imágenes\Movimientos\Rey.jpg");

Picture.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
```

de esta forma podrias armar la ruta a la imagen que quieres cargar en un picturebox para mostrarla

Comment: Es que ahí tengo un problema, por alguna razón no tengo el control PictureBox (asumo que será porque es en un WPF pero no estoy seguro la verdad), entonces lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que una imagen que ya está dentro de la interfaz, si antes mostraba una omagen, ahora me muestre la que está en la nueva dirección, y al probar con el código que mencionaste, no me lo acepta ya que me sale que los objetos no coinciden

Comment: Pero no mencionaste en ningun momento que es WPF, no aplica el codigo que puse ya que imagine era winform. Para acceder al control debes ponerle un name

Comment: WPF no tiene picturebox porque puedes poner una imagen en practicamente cualquier control, yo uso Rectangle para mostrar imágenes, pero puedes poner Grid, Rectangle, incluso borders y Labels, todos esos controles y otros pueden mostrar imagenes

Comment: @Leodev el equivalente aunque puede poner en cualquier control una imagen el equivalente es `Image` en Wpf del picturebox

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar una imagen no necesitas un PictureBox de Windows Forms porque no existe en WPF, en su lugar tienes muchos otros controles que pueden hacer lo mismo, te daré un ejemplo en el que muestro una imagen en un control **Rectangle**.

Por ejemplo, si tienes 3 piezas: Rey, Torre y Caballo, **guardas las imagenes como "Resource"** y cuando presiones el botón llamas al método que te pongo a continuación indicándole por parámetro la imagen a mostrar en el control Rectangle que -para el ejemplo- llamaremos *myRectangle*

El código sería el siguiente:

```
private void CambiarImagen(string imagen)
{
    Uri IMAGE_AYUDA = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imágenes/Ayuda.png");
    Uri IMAGE_REY = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imágenes/Movimientos/Rey.png");
    Uri IMAGE_TORRE = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imágenes/Movimientos/Torre.png");
    Uri IMAGE_CABALLO = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imágenes/Movimientos/Caballo.png");

    Uri CURRENT_URI = IMAGE_AYUDA ;
    switch (imagen)
    {
        case "Rey":
        CURRENT_URI = IMAGE_REY;
        break;
        case "Torre":
        CURRENT_URI = IMAGE_TORRE;
        break;
        case "Caballo":
        CURRENT_URI = IMAGE_CABALLO;
        break;                  
        default:
        CURRENT_URI = IMAGE_AYUDA;
        break;
    }

    BitmapImage _bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    _bitmap.BeginInit();
    _bitmap.UriSource = CURRENT_URI;
    _bitmap.EndInit();
    ImageBrush _brush = new ImageBrush(_bitmap);
    myRectangle.Fill = _brush;
}
```

Y con eso cada vez que llames al método cambiará la imagen por la que le indiques, solo debes establecer las rutas y recordar que los archivos estén dentro de la solución como "Resource" ya que así funcionará la declaración de las rutas en el método.

Puedes comprobarlo en las propiedades de la imagen una vez las pegues dentro de la solución.

[image: Ejemplo de acción de compilación sobre archivo de imagen en WPF]